# How to disable log in Laravel 4?

Tags: performance, codeigniter, logging, laravel-4

How to disable logging in Laravel4.

In codeigniter there is a config like below where we can disable the entire logging itself. Is there any configuration in laravel4 where we can disable it to gain the performance.

$config['log_threshold'] = 0; // <--------- zero to disable logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update: This is for Laravel 4.2***

Looking at Laravel [Error](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors) documentation:

You can disable the log by commenting two lines in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Error Logger
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here we will configure the error logger setup for the application which
| is built on top of the wonderful Monolog library. By default we will
| build a basic log file setup which creates a single file for logs.
|
*/

// Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
```

and

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // Log::error($exception);
});
```

Comment: Just instead: 
app/global/start.php

it's:
app/start/global.php